# Expected values from a database composition

Tags: expected-value

I have this kind of values:

```
letter Count                        
A   0.004315    
C   0.000701
D   0.002738
E   0.003056
F   0.001958
G   0.003456
```

That are counts(frequencies) of letters in a very large database and my doubt is about the expected values of this distribution. If all letters were equally distributed in the database and it normal probabilities 1/6. Then the expected value in this case is 1/6 or would be 0.004315 * 1/6.

I ask because I read different articles using both.

And how could I test the difference of letters counts against the counts of other data bases?